# How to combine 2 queries in same table with different group by ? (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to calculate On Time Arrival and Departure. Query to get On Time Departure:

```
SELECT DEPAIRPORT as AIRPORT,
    COUNT(case when A.STATUS = 'Scheduled' and 
    A.ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF is not null then 1 else NULL END) as SCHEDULED,
    COUNT(case when ((A.ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF+ interval '7' hour) - (A.SCHEDULED_DEPDT+ interval '7' hour))*24*60 <= '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000' and 
    A.ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF is not null then 1 else NULL END) as ONTIME
    FROM TABLE A GROUP BY DEPAIRPORT
```

and Query to calculate On Time Arrival:

```
SELECT COUNT(case when ((A.ACTUAL_BLOCKON + interval '7' hour) - (A.SCHEDULED_ARRDT+ interval '7' hour))*24*60 <= '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000' and 
    A.ACTUAL_BLOCKON is not null then 1 else NULL END) as ARRONTIME
    FROM TABLE A  
    GROUP BY ARRIVALAIRPORT
```

How to combine these queries into 1 single query so I can display it like this table:

`Name      #Schedule #OnTimeDeparture #ArrivalOntime
 AIRPORTX     41             35               20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the sample data and expected output, it is difficult to tell what exactly you want. If you want to combine the two datasets, you may put them in  `with` clauses and the then join them together(`LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` based on the output required for cases where arrival has happened yet or not)

```
WITH dep 
     AS (SELECT depairport AS airport, 
                count(CASE 
                        WHEN a.status = 'Scheduled' 
                             AND a.actual_blockoff IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                      END) AS scheduled, 
                count(CASE 
                        WHEN( ( a.actual_blockoff + interval '7' hour ) - ( 
                                    a.scheduled_depdt + interval '7' hour ) ) * 
                            24 * 
                            60 
                            <= 
                                  '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000' 
                            AND a.actual_blockoff IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                      END) AS ontime 
         FROM   tablea 
         GROUP  BY depairport), 
     arr 
     AS (SELECT arrivalairport AS airport, 
                count(CASE 
                        WHEN( ( a.actual_blockon + interval '7' hour ) - ( 
                                    a.scheduled_arrdt + interval '7' hour ) ) * 
                            24 * 
                            60 
                            <= 
                                  '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000' 
                            AND a.actual_blockon IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                      END)     AS arrontime 
         FROM   tablea 
         GROUP  BY arrivalairport) 
SELECT dep.airport   AS Name, 
       dep.scheduled AS "#Schedule", 
       dep.ontime    AS "#OnTimeDeparture", 
       arr.arrontime AS "#ArrivalOntime" 
FROM   dep 
       left join arr  -- Or Inner join depending on the expected output.
              ON ( dep.airport = arr.airport );
```

Comment: You just saved my life. the code above works perfectly and produce the result I want. Thanks a lot. I hope I can buy you a coffee one day. @Kaushik Nayak

Comment: @user1725887 : You're welcome. Sure, I would love to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
select 
    max(SCHEDULED) as SCHEDULED,
    max(ONTIME)    as ONTIME,
    max(ARRONTIME) as ARRONTIME
from (select 
      count(case when ... ) over(partition by DEPAIRPORT)     as SCHEDULED,
      count(case when ... ) over(partition by DEPAIRPORT)     as ONTIME,
      count(case when ... ) over(partition by ARRIVALAIRPORT) as ARRONTIME
   from a );
```

But I guess that your question is not complete. Also you need a key for join different flights.

Comment: I have tried the code above and didnt produce the result I want. but, thanks. @Alexandr